# Real device is not installing app.apk after deleting .gradle folder

Tags: android, flutter, adb

I was cleaning up my explorer and was stupid enough to delete the .gradle folder. When I recreated the folder, the real device was not install my flutter app and was stucked by "installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk.

In the logcat there are some weird errors, but I don't know if they have anything to do with the problem

```
2022-05-16 22:01:27.814 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2022-05-16 22:01:27.815 1286-1467/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
2022-05-16 22:01:27.819 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2022-05-16 22:01:27.819 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2022-05-16 22:01:27.819 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2022-05-16 22:01:28.450 670-670/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats
2022-05-16 22:01:28.453 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2022-05-16 22:01:28.454 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2022-05-16 22:01:28.454 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2022-05-16 22:01:28.454 1286-1467/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
2022-05-16 22:01:31.345 802-802/? E/: [E/capacity_limit_control] not demo version, not set power control prop!
2022-05-16 22:01:31.464 670-670/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats
2022-05-16 22:01:31.476 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2022-05-16 22:01:31.476 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2022-05-16 22:01:31.476 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2022-05-16 22:01:31.477 1286-1467/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
2022-05-16 22:01:34.486 670-670/? E/WifiHAL: enter wifi_get_link_stats
2022-05-16 22:01:34.498 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2022-05-16 22:01:34.498 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2022-05-16 22:01:34.498 776-776/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2022-05-16 22:01:34.499 1286-1467/? E/WificondControl: Noise: 0, Snr: -1, Chload: -1
```

Comment: The logcat output you have posted does not contain anything regarding an installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can open Android Studio, even if you don't often use it and open your project directory, and the gradle will re-sync, and the .gradle folder will be recreated.

In case this did not work, what you can do is init a new project using `flutter create projectname`, then copying all your assets and lib folders in addition to the pubspec.yaml file to your newly created project, and it will work just fine.